How to count NA values per group in R?
I'd like to count how many values are NA per group. Here is the data frame:
  ID   x   y   z
1  1 1.5 3.2 6.7
2  2 0.0 4.0 8.1
3  3 3.0  NA 2.4
4  3  NA 1.2  NA

I'd like to output for each ID (1, 2 and 3) the sum of the NA values for each variable. So, in this instance, it would look something like this:
     ID x y z
[1,] 1  0 0 0
[2,] 2  0 0 0
[3,] 3  1 1 1

I tried to use the code:
df5 %>% group_by(ID) %>% sapply(function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
but the output was incorrect:
ID  x  y  z  0  1  1  1
It shows the NA values, but not the corresponding ID where the NA are found.
I also tried to use the code:
df1 %>%  group_by(group) %>%  summarise(count = sum(is.na(number)), .groups = 'drop')
But it only works if I have one variable for which I want to know the number of NAs.

Maybe summarise(df, across(x:z, ~sum(is.na(.x))), .by=ID)

This question is similar to: dplyr summarise across when column is sometimes missing. And this one too. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
